# Appengie Oauth: Spreadsheet api client.get_spreadsheets() returns error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, gdata, google-sheets-api

trying to list the google spreadsheet using `oauth`  & `GData` in Google Appengine. But i'm getting following error. Anything wrong in my code?

Please advise.

```
File "/home/RKS/Appengine/test/main.py", line 99, in get
    feed = client.get_spreadsheets()
  File "/home/RKS/Appengine/test/gdata/spreadsheets/client.py", line 78, in get_spreadsheets
    desired_class=desired_class, **kwargs)
  File "/home/RKS/Appengine/test/gdata/client.py", line 640, in get_feed
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/RKS/Appengine/test/gdata/client.py", line 278, in request
    version=get_xml_version(self.api_version))
  File "/home/RKS/Appengine/test/atom/core.py", line 520, in parse
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
  File "<string>", line 125, in XML
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import webapp2
import logging
from google.appengine.api import users

import gdata.auth
import gdata.gauth
import gdata.client
import gdata.service
import gdata.spreadsheets
import gdata.spreadsheets.client
import gdata.spreadsheets.data

SETTINGS = {
    'APP_NAME': 'hidden',  # intentionally hidden
    'CONSUMER_KEY': 'hidden',
    'CONSUMER_SECRET': 'hidden',
    'SCOPES': ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'],
    'CALLBACK_URL': '',
    'SIG_METHOD': gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1
}

class FetchToken(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        current_uid = users.get_current_user().user_id()
        if isinstance(gdata.gauth.AeLoad(current_uid), gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken):
            # the user has gone through the process before
            self.redirect('/')
        else:
              # the user has not gone through this process, or the authorization has expired or been revoked.
            SETTINGS['CALLBACK_URL'] = 'http://%s/HandleOAuthCallback' % self.request.host
            client = gdata.client.GDClient()
            request_token = client.GetOAuthToken(
                SETTINGS['SCOPES'],
                SETTINGS['CALLBACK_URL'],
                SETTINGS['CONSUMER_KEY'],
                consumer_secret=SETTINGS['CONSUMER_SECRET'])

            gdata.gauth.AeSave(request_token, current_uid)
            self.redirect(str(request_token.generate_authorization_url()))


class HandleOAuthCallback(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        current_uid = users.get_current_user().user_id()
        client = gdata.client.GDClient()
        saved_request_token = gdata.gauth.AeLoad(current_uid)
        request_token = gdata.gauth.AuthorizeRequestToken(saved_request_token, self.request.uri)
        access_token = client.GetAccessToken(request_token)
        gdata.gauth.AeSave(access_token, current_uid)
        self.redirect('/')


class GetDocsList(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not users.get_current_user():
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url('/'))
        else:
            current_uid = users.get_current_user().user_id()
            if isinstance(gdata.gauth.AeLoad(current_uid), gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken):
                # the user has gone through the process before

                access_token = gdata.gauth.AeLoad(current_uid)
                client = gdata.service.GDataService()

                oauth_input_params = gdata.auth.OAuthInputParams(
                    gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1,
                    SETTINGS['CONSUMER_KEY'],
                    SETTINGS['CONSUMER_SECRET'])  # consumer_secret=

                oauth_token = gdata.auth.OAuthToken(
                    key=access_token.token,
                    secret=access_token.token_secret,
                    scopes=SETTINGS['SCOPES'],
                    oauth_input_params=oauth_input_params)

                client.SetOAuthToken(oauth_token)

                client = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()

                feed = client.get_spreadsheets()

            else:
                self.redirect('/FetchToken')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/HandleOAuthCallback', HandleOAuthCallback), ('/', GetDocsList), ('/FetchToken', FetchToken)], debug=False)
```

Comment: The Google DrEdit tutorials include OAuth2. I found them a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching to OAuth2, and most of my answer will explain how to solve your problem by doing that. However, before trying to switch to OAuth2 I suggest you try this one line change, which may be a quick solution to your problem. The first thing I would try is adding a header to your client as follows.

```
client.additional_headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token,
}
```

I have an application using the GData spreadsheets API with OAuth2 and adding that header was necessary for it to work. If I took that header out, I would get an error like the one you described.

Now, on to the answer:
Using OAuth2 in App Engine to do what you're trying to do is even simpler than what you've already done. Here's how it is done.

First create an OAuth2 decorator. (I describe where to create your client ID and client secret at the end of the answer.)

```
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
GlobalOAuth2Decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
  client_id=OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret=OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
  scope='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
)
```

Then use this decorator when you create your request handler.

```
class SpreadsheetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @GlobalOAuth2Decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
    client.additional_headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % GlobalOAuth2Decorator.credentials.access_token,
    }
```

Notice that I'm using SpreadsheetsService instead of SpreadsheetsClient. This has been working for me, though I haven't given SpreadsheetsClient a try (the client might actually be easier to use).

Once you've created this `client` object you can use it to read and write spreadsheets as you like. For example `sheets = client.GetSpreadsheetsFeeds()` will give you a list of spreadsheets that you can access.

Lastly, make sure to include the OAuth handler in your list of handlers when you create the application:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([..., (GlobalOAuth2Decorator.callback_path, GlobalOAuth2Decorator.callback_handler())]
```

In order for OAuth2 to work, you have to go to your developer console at https://console.developers.google.com and 1) select your app, 2) from the Credentials menu create a new Client ID (this will generate a client ID and secret for you), and 3) from the Consent Screen menu give your application an email address and name.